# What is the process name of WinDRBD?

Tags: drbd

Now I am using WinDRBD on Windows Server 2019

So far, I have checked whether DRBD is running with the command below.

```
drbdadm status foo
```

However, I need to write some code in the batch file to check if DRBD is working.

I looked at the process in the windows task manager.
However, I did not find the process.

I may have missed it. What is the process name of WinDRBD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The services have the following names:

*windrbd* (Kernel driver)

*windrbdumhelper*

*windrbdlog*

Comment: Thank you! batistuta09

Comment: welcome! If you use DRBD for storage replication, take a look at Starwind vsan (free version) – it is a windows service (without Linux kernel API emulation) with integrated powershell management. https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san-free